# What is the eigenvector in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When row-reducing the matrix I have with the eigenvalue, this is the result:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &1  &|0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &|0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &|0 
\end{bmatrix}.$

The eigenvectors will be $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$

Can someone explain to me why, because I thought the only eigenvector would be $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: What led you to believe that the eigenspace would be one-dimensional? And even if it was, $(-1,0,1)^T$ isn’t the _only_ eigenvector: any nonzero scalar multiple of it is also an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

You get $x+z=0$ but no constraint on $y$. Your eigenvector is $(x~y~-x)=x(1~0~-1)+y(0~1~0)$. Note that this generates two linearly independent eigenvectors: $(-1,0,1)$ for $x=-1,y=0$ and $(0,1,0)$ for $x=0,y=1$. Any other eigenvector for this eigenvalue is a linear combination of these two eigenvectors.